# How does Oracle evaluate a hierarchical query with "connect by rownum <= n"

Tags: oracle

```
With A as (

   SELECT 'A' ID FROM DUAL

   UNION ALL 

   SELECT 'B' FROM DUAL

   UNION ALL

   SELECT 'C' FROM DUAL
  )

  SELECT ID 
       , LEVEL AS LVL 
       , ROWNUM 
       , SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(LEVEL,'->') AS LV_PATH
       , SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(ID,'->') AS ID_PATH
    FROM A
  CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 3
```

```
Result
  ID      LVL   ROWNUM     LV_PATH     ID_PATH
   A       1      1         ->1          ->A
   A       2      2         ->1->2       ->A->A
   A       3      3         ->1->2->3    ->A->A->A
   B       1      4         ->1          ->B
   C       1      5         ->1          ->B

[why B and C has 1 level !?]
```

in this query's result , B and C has only 1 value( level? ) 
but A has 3 value and level (and ID_PATH result consist only A)

i understand that use connect by level is make hierarchy structure so i know it will make n + n^n column

but i dont know why connect by rownum show only these values ...

please help me T T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hierarchical query connects one row in the hierarchy to another row according to the criterion `rownum <= 3`.

Firstly, it's important to understand that `rownum` is a pseudocolumn which is generated *when* and *only if* the query decides that a row will be generated; it always starts at `1` for the first record emitted, and only increments as each subsequent record is emitted (that's why you never get results when something like `where rownum > 1` is executed).

Secondly, it's important to understand that in Oracle, a hierarchical query is built using a depth-first search.

Your starting rowset is:

```
1. 'A'
2. 'B'
3. 'C'
```

The first row generated by the query is:

```
1. 'A' rownum=1 level=1
```

The query now goes back and probes the original rowset for any immediate "children" of this row. It finds the first record `'A'`. The condition to determine whether this row is a child of our first row is `rownum <= 3`. Since `rownum` for the row to be generated is `2`, the condition is satisfied; so this row is emitted:

```
2. 'A' -> 'A' rownum=2 level=2
```

The query now probes the rowset *again* for any immediate "children" of this row. It finds the first record `'A'`. The condition `rownum <= 3` is again checked; since `rownum` will now be `3`, the condition is satisfied; so this row is emitted:

```
3. 'A' -> 'A' -> 'A' rownum=3 level=3
```

The query now probes the rowset *again* for any immediate "children" of this new row. However, `rownum` is going to be `4` for the new row so it fails to find any "children".

Therefore it goes back to row 2 generated previously and continues searching the rowset for any other children; again, `rownum` is going to be `4` so it still fails to find any more children. It does the same for row 1 and fails to find any other children.

Finally, it has got back to the root of the tree and it moves forward to the next record in the rowset:

```
4. 'B' rownum=4 level=1
```

It does the same thing there, searching the rowset for any children of this record, and fails due to the condition.

It finally gets to the last record in the rowset:

```
5. 'C' rownum=5 level=1
```

It also fails to find any children of this record, and the query has finished.

Comment: That's perfect to understand wow : ▷  thanks for the perfect answer!